# CUDA_ERROR_COMPAT_NOT_SUPPORTED_ON_DEVICE when running guppy basecaller

Tags: guppy

I have tried to run the ONT basecaller guppy. I have run this code several times before without any issues. Now (following a reboot) it is producing the error message:

`[guppy/error] main: CUDA error at /builds/ofan/ont_core_cpp/ont_core/common/cuda_common.cpp:203: CUDA_ERROR_COMPAT_NOT_SUPPORTED_ON_DEVICE [guppy/warning] main: An error occurred in the basecaller. Aborting.`

Is this a compatibility problem, and if so what can I do to solve it?
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-72-generic x86_64)
and Guppy Basecalling Software, (C) Oxford Nanopore Technologies, Limited. Version 4.0.14+8d3226e, client-server API version 2.1.0

Here is my guppy code:

`guppy_basecaller -i fast5/pass -r --device cuda:0 -s hac_fastqs_demul -c /opt/ont/ont-guppy/data/dna_r9.4.1_450bps_hac.cfg --num_callers 4 --require_barcodes_both_ends --trim_barcodes --detect_mid_strand_barcodes --barcode_kits "EXP-PBC001"`

Answer (score 3):

This issue was fixed by rebooting.